# After updating data source and calling reloadData, the data source is unchanged in cellForItem

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that is populated by a data source that is an array of a protocol type. The data source is declared in my view controller `SomeViewController`.

```
var dataSource = [SomeProtocol]()
```

I have set both the data Source and the delegate of the collection view to `self`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    someDataSourcePopulationMethod()
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
}
```

The data source methods are implemented in an extension of `SomeViewController`.

```
extension SomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let item = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        switch item.type {
            case .typeA:
                // Dequeue cell and configure
                return cellTypeA
            case .typeB:
                // Dequeue cell and configure
                return cellTypeB
        }
    }

}
```

Everything works fine. Until I filter out a certain type from the data source array and reload the data.

```
func filterDataAndReload() {
    dataSource = dataSource.filter { !($0 is TypeA) }
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Let's say that the first item in the data source was originally of `TypeA`. This code should remove that first item (and all other items of `TypeA`) and update the collection view to display only items of `TypeB`.

But it doesn't work. I am still seeing the cell for `TypeA`.

I've checked that the data source is indeed being filtered, and it is. When I put a break point on the filter method, I can see that the data source only contains items of `TypeB`.

But when I place a breakpoint in the `cellForItem` method, I see that the data source hasn't been updated at all.

Why could this be?

There is nothing asynchronous going on, so I shouldn't need to dispatch to the main thread. (Although I have tried that.)

I've also tried cleaning the project and rebuilding.

**EDIT:**

I've done a bit more investigation.

If the TypeA cells are visible when the filter method is called, they don't change. In fact, they take the place of TypeB cells that should be there. I can scroll away from them and then scroll back, and they still don't change.

But if I scroll away from the TypeA cells and THEN use the filter method, when I scroll back to where the TypeA cells originally were, they are no longer there.

Comment: If I were you I wouldn't reload the entire collection view. I'd call `collectionView.deleteItems(at:)` inside of `collectionView.performBatchUpdates` after you determine the indexes of TypeA.

Comment: That's a great idea, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem of why my data source is incorrect in cellForItem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I tested it with buttons that call the filter functions and they work correctly.  If the "Filter Strings" button is tapped, the collection removes all the Int values and displays only the number strings.  Same goes for the "Filter Ints" button.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dataSource: [Any] = []

    @IBAction func filterStringsBtnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        filterStrings()
    }

    @IBAction func filterIntsBtnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        filterInts()
    }

    @IBAction func resetDataBtnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dataSource = [1,2,3,"four","five","six",7,8,"nine","ten"]
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        populateData()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }

    func populateData() {
        dataSource = [1,2,3,"four","five","six",7,8,"nine","ten"]
    }

    func filterStrings() {
        dataSource = dataSource.filter { $0 is String }
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func filterInts() {
        dataSource = dataSource.filter { $0 is Int }
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let item = dataSource[indexPath.row]

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        switch item {
        case let stringItem as String:
            cell.myCellLabel.text = " \(stringItem) "
            return cell
        case let numberItem as Int:
            cell.myCellLabel.text = " \(numberItem) "
            return cell
        default:
            print("This should not happen")
            return cell
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: The full code is available at this repository: `https://github.com/Wattholm/TestCollectionView`